# kernel memcpy actually copyed more bytes than the specified length

Tags: kernel, crash

I have a kernel crash problem.

```
BUG: unable to handle page fault for address: ffff88812c410000
```

Stack information shows

```
ip_frag_next-->skb_copy_bits-->memcpy_orig+52
```

The analysis shows that the incoming memcpy call was for 620 bytes, but when it crashed, it found that it had already copied 107520 bytes. The result is an access exception.

What would cause this to happen?

```
RDX: current offset
RBX: specified length of memcpy
RAX: dest pointer of memcpy
RDI: current position of dest
    [exception RIP: memcpy_orig+52]
    RIP: ffffffff80a98ed4  RSP: ffffc90000067698  RFLAGS: 00010282
    RAX: ffff88812c3f5c24  RBX: 000000000000026c  RCX: 0000000000001cfc
    RDX: fffffffffffe5e4c  RSI: ffff888002b3014a  RDI: ffff88812c40ffe4
    RBP: ffff88812c3f5c24   R8: 657fc3fb17a4d6f3   R9: 763c3854b6c4e057
    R10: 55cc9b5ed64cab61  R11: 2afd84bbcdd9c7a3  R12: ffffffff814cbbc0
    R13: 000000000000026c  R14: 0000000000001cfc  R15: 0000000000001f68


crash> dis -r memcpy_orig+52
0xffffffff80a98ea0 :       mov    %rdi,%rax
0xffffffff80a98ea3 :     cmp    $0x20,%rdx
0xffffffff80a98ea7 :     jb     0xffffffff80a98f27 
0xffffffff80a98ea9 :     cmp    %dil,%sil
0xffffffff80a98eac :    jl     0xffffffff80a98ee3 
0xffffffff80a98eae :    sub    $0x20,%rdx
0xffffffff80a98eb2 :    sub    $0x20,%rdx
0xffffffff80a98eb6 :    mov    (%rsi),%r8
0xffffffff80a98eb9 :    mov    0x8(%rsi),%r9
0xffffffff80a98ebd :    mov    0x10(%rsi),%r10
0xffffffff80a98ec1 :    mov    0x18(%rsi),%r11
0xffffffff80a98ec5 :    lea    0x20(%rsi),%rsi
0xffffffff80a98ec9 :    mov    %r8,(%rdi)
0xffffffff80a98ecc :    mov    %r9,0x8(%rdi)
0xffffffff80a98ed0 :    mov    %r10,0x10(%rdi)
0xffffffff80a98ed4 :    mov    %r11,0x18(%rdi)
```

From the code, memcpy should only copy the specified 620 bytes of data. But instead it copies more than 107520 bytes of data, which ultimately leads to an access exception

Comment: It looks like a hardware problem with your CPU.I spent 8 months tracking down a mainframe intermittent where it branched off to -1 on an interrupt. Somewhere, your CPU picked up a memory location "containing" 620, and saw something else, like `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF" and proccede "normally" until the page fault. Run all the CPU and Memory tests you can find.

Comment: HI waltinator, 可以多提供点信息麼，如何进行CPU和MEM检查？